# Void Pointers with Inherited Classes

Tags: c++

I have a class, `A`, which requires static event handlers. I needed the static event handlers because an interrupt is calling the event handler.

```
class A {
private:
    static void (*fn1)();

public:
    A();
    static void setFn1(void (*function)(void));
    static void onEvent();
};

A::A() { }

void A::setFn1(void (*function)(void)) {
    fn1 = function;
}

void A::onEvent() {
    A::fn1();
}
```

I want to inherit `A` based upon the application and create the event
handler logic in the child, using `fn2` here.

```
class B : public A{
public:
    B();
    void fn2();
};

B::B() {
    A::setFn1(&fn2);
}

void B::fn2() {...}
```

When I call: `A::setFn1(&fn2)` I get the following compiler error.

> #169 argument of type "void (B::*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (*)()

My mind is all loopy with these void-pointers and I do not know if I am even using the proper design anymore.  The `A` class contains all my utility methods.  The `B` class contains my application specific functionality.

Comment: These are not void pointers! They are pointers to functions that take no arguments and return nothing.

Answer (score 3):

A non-static member function is not a free function, the types differ. You cannot use a non-static member function as if it was a pointer to a function:

```
struct test {
   void foo();
   static void bar();
};

&test::foo --> void (test::*)()
&test::bar --> void (*)()
```

I won't go in as much as recommending changing the function to be `static` as I don't find the current design particularly useful. But you can take this and try to rethink a design that will make more sense. (A single *callback* function for all the process? Why inheritance at all? A *user-defined* constructor that does the same as the compiler generated? In a class that should not be instantiated?...)

Comment: I am using a micro-controller and I need to hook into the interrupt table.  I am having those interrupts call the static members of my base class.  The parent class is the utility class while the children will be the application classes--they would all be singletons.  Right now all the code is in C.  I want to leverage OOD by bringing it into C++ but I am running into problems with this machine level interface.

Comment: @zam664: You should be aware of what the calling convention in the platform is, and you might want to add `extern "C"`. The use of inheritance makes no sense at all. Why does the derived type not register the function directly with the interrupts, why the extra indirection? Even if you want the indirection, `A` has no *interface* that you need to mimic, `B` can be completely unrelated (and that could make more sense). You can also use a plain good old free function, leveraging OOD and hammering OOD everywhere are different things, use the tool that better fits the task.

Answer (score 2):

> When I call: A::setFn1(&fn2) I get the following compiler error.

`fn2` is a *member function* of a `B`, so you have to qualify its name:

```
A::setFn1(&B::fn2)
//         ^^^
```

Moreover, `fn2` should be `static`, because non-`static` member functions actually work on an implicit `this` pointer, so they are accepting an argument:

```
class B : public A{
public:
    B();
    static void fn2();
//  ^^^^^^
};
```

With these two changes, your program should compile.

Comment: When I did the A::setFn1(&B::fn2)  I get the following compile error:
#278 name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name.  Also, this may be the design problem in that I need fn2 to be non-static because it needs to use non-static member variables.

Comment: @zam664: Are you sure you are copying everything exactly? It compiles [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3SRz1U$74).

Comment: If I make fn2() static--yes, it compiles.  But I need that to be non-static to access the member variables, and it doesn't compile.  I really think I have a design issue because I need to cross this static/non-static barrier.